# Examples of groups where any non-identity element has order $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is the following proposition true?

> For every $n \in \mathbb N$ there exists a group $G$ such that every element $g \in G\setminus \{e\}$ has order $ord(g)=n$.

Before someone asks, this isn't homework - curiosity rather.

Comment: If $n$ is composite, then no.  If $n=ab$ then, if $g$ has order $n$, $g^a$ has order $b$.  If $n$ is prime then the cyclic group of order $n$ works.

Comment: The site's dislike of "problem statements questions" like this aren't just about homework. Two concerete reasons for showing some effort are: (1) It is polite, and (2) making an effort can often help you solve the problem for yourself, thus bypassing the site altogether (which is a good thing, and saves everyone effort and time; see also [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/10513)). Here, trying some easy examples amongst the most basic of groups (cyclic groups, or even groups of order up to $6$, say) would give you a good insight into the problem, which you could have shared.

Comment: (Also, with my cynical hat on, saying "this is not homework" doesn't actually mean that it is not homework!)

Comment: @M.C. I am not offended; I mostly just wanted to correct the idea that "a good question must contain what you tried, because of homework stuff". Writing a good question takes time and effort, and moreover just saying what you tried doesn't automatically make it a good question. Everything is more complicated than that :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. With the exception of the trivial group $\{e\}$, for which the condition is vacuously true regardless of $n$. And so I will assume you meant "(...) there exists a **non-trivial** group $G$ (...)".

If $p$ is a prime number dividing $n$ and $g$ is of order $n$, then $g^{n/p}$ is of order $p$. Such $n$ will be a counterexample as long as $n\neq p$. And so this excludes all composite $n$.

On the other hand "yes" if $n=p$ is prime. One such example is $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^k$ for any cardinal (even infinite) $k\geq 1$. For an interesting infinite, nonabelian group such that every nontrivial element is of order $p$ see [Tarski monster group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group).

Comment: For $p > 2$ there are also nonabelian groups in which all non-identity elements have the same prime order.